# What is the state of the art setup for encrypted home directories which allow remote SSH login in 2022/2024?

Tags: server, ssh, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

## Question

What is the state of the art replacement for ecryptfs, while allowing user logins through SSH without a "master" full disk encryption (= FDE) password?

## Context

A long time ago Ubuntu offered ecryptfs backed encrypted home directories in the installer. This was fine and allowed me to setup servers which I could power on through the power button or Wake on LAN and connect to the machine through SSH.

I have been told a few years ago that ecryptfs is not considered safe or state of the art any more. Although I can see that [ecryptfs-utils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/ecryptfs-utils) is still available. So in theory I could continue setting up servers as before, until I encounter a serious problem.

I heard about [Systemd-homed](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-homed), but so far I have not heard a confirmation that this is a solution that Ubuntu developers and maintainers recommend or embrace.

I have also been using [Dm-crypt/Mounting_at_login](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Mounting_at_login) before switching to use the typical encrypted partitions layouts offered by the respective Linux distribution.

If you  are confused about my question and how this has worked in the past:

```bash
ls -1a /home/
.ecryptfs
my_user

ls -1a /home/.ecryptfs/
my_user

ls -1a /home/.ecryptfs/my_user/
.ecryptfs
.Private
.ssh
```

Some additional configuration was put in place to store the encrypted files of a user under `/home/.ecryptfs/my_user/.Private`. `/home/.ecryptfs/my_user/.ecryptfs` contained some scripts and metadata. `/home/.ecryptfs/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys` contained unencrypted content, and eventually I create a symlink from `/home/.ecryptfs/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `/home/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Voila, remote SSH login without providing an FDE password. The rest was handled by ecryptfs. So if I could get a similar setup with state of the art technology and without any references to ecryptfs while it is not being used, that would be fantastic.

I can wait until 24.04 LTS is released if something is currently in the works that makes this easier.

With regards to security concerns: servers of this kind have a fixed location and will not be moved around like laptops. The door to the room is protected with an electronic lock (and api logging).

## Requirements

- At least the user data (home directory) on a server should be encrypted with state of the art and strong encryption.
- Login on a machine with SSH should be possible
- There should be no interruption in the boot up process of the server by a password prompt to unlock file systems

  - Technically I could use an iKVM, but I prefer to not do it for this use case
  - Pressing the power button or sending a Wake on LAN packet should be all that is required as far as hands on with the server is required between power on self test (POST) and completion of the boot process by starting SSHd.

---

I tried looking for different solutions, as you can see, but this seems to be a very specific use case that was once somewhat common knowledge but seems to have become buried under SEO, LLM and groupthink.

---

## Edit 2023-10-19

### Method 1

> "TPM-backed full disk encryption"

Oh this is indeed brand new in Ubuntu and I didn't catch up with the news. https://ubuntu.com/blog/tpm-backed-full-disk-encryption-is-coming-to-ubuntu

> Biggest drawback: remote access is a nightmare to set up.

Please tell me more about the nightmare.

The mainboard in this machine has a TPM header and the module is inexpensive. I would still consider pursuing this solution, even though I have been a strong opponent of TPM in the past.

No valuable data is supposed to be stored on the root and home volume in my setup.

### Method 2 and Method 3

Okay, so I have my home directory encrypted, what do I need to do to be able to login remotely with SSH? I found some articles and discussions that suggested extending the configuration of SSHd to look in a different place for `authorized_keys`. With recent versions of SSH the following configuration fragment should be possible:

```bash
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/authorized_keys
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile /home/.ssh/%u/authorized_keys
```

I have not tested yet if this works.

`/home/.ssh/%u/authorized_keys` should translate to `/home/.ssh/my_user/authorized_keys` if we want to be consistent with my example above. It's similar to the convention used by `ecryptfs` and I wonder why I didn't think of it earlier.

Or did you intend to do something different? How to continue? Logging in with the SSH key doesn't automatically mount the volume, does it? Is there some consensus of what script to use, or perhaps a systemd functionality, or does everyone implement a script on their own (please don't :-( )?

Comment: Some links I found while checking how people outside the Ubuntu community approach TPM FDE: https://blastrock.github.io/fde-tpm-sb.html https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/encrypting-drives-using-LUKS/ https://fedoramagazine.org/automatically-decrypt-your-disk-using-tpm2/ Don't rely on my comments. I will clean up and remove my comments when I found a solution to my question.

Comment: "Is there some consensus of what script to use, or perhaps a systemd functionality, or does everyone implement a script on their own" In the long run, I'd bet on systemd-homed. I think it already supports mounting encrypted home directories on demand, and while Canonical may dither around and do a bit of NIH nonsense, they do tend to go with the mainstream in the end for desktop anyway (Unity v GNOME Shell, Mir v Wayland)

Comment: One workaround may be not to encrypt the whole home, but to encrypt a "Private" folder/container for the sensitive files.

Comment: @muru I agree with your criticism.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 main methods. The 3rd one seems the easiest and most appropriate but just to be thorough all 3 ...

##### Method 1

"TPM-backed full disk encryption" is the method the installer supports. You need to do that from the installer. Biggest drawback: remote access is a nightmare to set up. During installation:

- Erase disk and install Ubuntu option
- check "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security"
- insert key

Loosing the key is fatal for the whole system.

##### Method 2

Encrypting only a partition then the current method would be using LUKS. You can no longer do this from the installer but it is rather easy to do after install. Biggest drawback: altering the size of the partition is annoying.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/{device}
```

and setting an encryption key is all it takes. This allows you to boot but needs the encryption key if you do this using `/home`. I would keep `/home` as a directory inside `/` and use your encrypted partition only for personal data. Passphrase needed to open the partition but it does not stop booting and using then system.

##### Method 3

And then there is a virtual encrypted partition using LUKS. With this one you can boot and use your system. Passphrase only needed if you want to open the container. Setup:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of={dir/filename} bs=1M count=1024
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat {/dir/filename}
```

This is the most flexible method: extending the size is easy so it solves the partition encryption. Easy backup and easy transfer to another system if you need it for a new system.

Something I do: use a container, have a script inside the container. When container is opened execute script. Script puts files in the correct place (like ssh files, also works for gnome keyring if you don't want passwords on the system but I use a password safe myself). And those files get removed during boot, during shutdown, and when closing the container.

> I found some articles and discussions that suggested extending the configuration of SSHd to look in a different place for authorized_keys

I circumvented this by not encrypting `/home` but this would indeed be a solution. SSH accepts this:

```
/etc/ssh/authorized_keys_{username}
```

where {username} can then use the private key to connect. Requires a restart of sshd ofcourse.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. Can you please take a look and extend your answer?

Comment: If I LUKS encrypt my `/home/$USERNAME/` partition will it as for the passphrase when I login locally and by ssh?

Comment: Can you use "dropbear"? Never used is but a co-worker does ( here is a how to: https://www.cyberciti.biz/security/how-to-unlock-luks-using-dropbear-ssh-keys-remotely-in-linux/ )